# Adding functions inside model breaks MVVM or SOLID principles in Dart / Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, oop, mvvm, solid-principles

In Dart we add methods like `toJson()` and `Model.fromJson()` inside model, does this breaks MVVM or SOLID principles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't, it's totally the opposite, it's recommended to set model JSON converters factories and methods of a model inside its implementation.

check this:

[JSON and serialization](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/json)

the goal of those methods is to handle serializing your model, to make your life easier when working with APIs, and external data...

I would say that what's not a good practice, is to try to handle JSON serialization inside your business logic.